# Force symbolic usage in PDF or distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions

I want to create a custom distribution based on a `SmoothKernelDistribution` or `KernelMixtureDistribution` as so:

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 1.2], 1000];
skd1 = KernelMixtureDistribution[data1];
custom[a_] := ProbabilityDistribution[PDF[skd1, x+a], {x, 0, 10}, Assumptions -> a >= 0 && a < 2.5];
```

Then I want to fit the `a` parameter as so:

```
data3 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[6, 1.2], 1000];
FindDistributionParameters[data3, custom[a], ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", Method -> {"FindMaximum"}}]
```

However, this will just grind away for hours with no result.  I can do something like this in about 1 second:

```
custom[a_] := ProbabilityDistribution[a PDF[skd1, x], {x, 0, 10}, Assumptions -> a >= 0 && a < 2.5];
```

So this tells me that putting `x+a` in for the argument to the PDF is what's causing the bottleneck.  Is there a better/faster way to force a parameter in this place?

Comment: I may be thinking about this wrong but it seems the result for your example should be approx `a=-1` i.e. outside your assumptions.

Comment: I thought to not use `FindDistributionParameters` and instead do something like `NMaximize[LogLikelihood[custom[a], data3], a]`  This is not immediately working or is slow but something to think about.

Comment: george2079:  Yep, you're right, I was getting confused about which way I was going with the distribution.  It's grinding away right now with the parameter selection relaxed to -1.5 < a < 1.5

Also, I'm trying NMaximize now on another kernel, so we'll see what comes out... Thank you for the options to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would describe the motivation for proceeding in the manner you've described, I might be able to help more (as what you describe is doable but not usual).

Here are two estimators:  Method of moments (the quickest) and maximum likelihood for a shift from the distribution generated from a random sample in the form of a `KernelMixtureDistribution`:

```
(* Generate a distribution *)
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 1.2], 1000];
skd1 = KernelMixtureDistribution[data1];

(* Mean of distribution *)
μ = Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] skd1]
(* 4.929814990602076 *)

(* Take a random sample from that generated distribution but shifted by 1 *)
data3 = 1 + RandomVariate[skd1, 100];

(* Estimate a by method of moments *)
mom = Mean[data3] - μ
(* 1.0098336468866025 *)

(* Estimate a by maximum likelihood *)
logL = LogLikelihood[skd1, data3 - a];
mle = a /. FindMaximum[logL, {{a, mom}}, AccuracyGoal -> 20][[2]]
(* 1.0009715243841062 *)

Show[Plot[logL, {a, -5, 5}],
 ListPlot[{{mle, logL /. a -> mle}}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Kernel likelihood]

Comment: Here's some additional info:  The distribution I need to actually work with doesn't have a nice analytical formula.  It's like an exponential decay, then goes flat, then cuts off quickly.  It's like a slide that goes down, stays flat, then plummets to the X-axis.  I hope that's clear...  Anyway, with such a weird distribution, I'm not sure that finding a mean is useful (is it?).  I have a set of experimental data, and I have a monte carlo generated set of data, but the MC data is shifted.  I want to know the best shift parameter to make the simulation match the data.

Comment: No part of my answer assumes an analytical model (nice or not so nice).  A distribution is created from `data1`.  It is not created directly from a normal distribution.  The estimate of the shift is created from `data3` and the kernel distribution.  Again, no nice distribution is assumed.  If the only difference is a shift in location, then one doesn't need to know the analytical form to estimate the shift.  Maybe you should be asking this at CrossValidated StackExchange?

Comment: Ok I've been playing with your suggestion and it works perfectly!  I especially love the visualization of the likelihood, though it takes longer than the MLE to plot... Still, very nice to have!  Thank you again!